# Angular not updating datalist DOM element

Tags: angular

I have this input field:

```
<input type="text" list="myList">
<datalist id="myList">
  <option *ngFor="let loc of locationList">{{ loc.description }}</option>
</datalist>
```

This is a pretty straightforward thing. The `datalist` provides autocomplete options and it is populated by an array. The array is updated by a service.

Here comes the problem. Regardless that the service upgrades the array - it can be checked on the console, it's actually updating - the contents of the `datalist` will not change until another keypress.

In Chrome I found that `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` eliminates the problem. But under Firefox it persists. Firefox only updates the `datalist` when the user presses Backspace. It doesn't if he just keeps typing.

Is there a way to tell Angular to refresh all the bindings tied to this array?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your service updates the `locationList` synchronously (not as a result of an XHR or a timeout). It's caused by the Angular's change detection and refresh strategy and zones (zone.js). Check the following article, it's important to know more about it:

- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Actually it calls Google Maps JS API and returns an Observable. Thanks, I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using HTML 5, not Angular. You are dependant from the browsers implementations.
I suggest you to use the old fashion method :

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input type="text" class="validate filter-input" [(ngModel)]=query (keyup)=filter()>
    </div>
    <div class="suggestions" *ngIf="locationList.length > 0">
        <ul *ngFor="let loc of locationList" >
            <li >
                <a (click)="select(loc)">{{loc.description}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update your component with this methods :

```
query: string;
locationList: [];

filter() {
    if (this.query !== ""){
        this.locationList = this.service.getLocations().filter(function(el){
            return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        }.bind(this));
    }else{
        this.locationList = [];
    }
}

select(item){
    this.query = item;
    this.locationList = [];
}
```

Here a more detailed working example : http://4dev.tech/2016/03/tutorial-creating-an-angular2-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

If you call a Javascript outside of Angular, you have to use NgZone (based on ZoneJS framework) to update your Angular model.

For example :

```
import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class YourComponent { {

  locationList: any[];
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  updateDataList() {
    googleMapsToPromise().then(locations => {
         this.locationList = location;
         this.ngZone.run(() => {
           console.log('model updated') 
         });
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Documentation here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html

And here an example of googleMapsToPromise implementation : https://jamesbedont.com/2016/03/23/GoogleMapsApiIntroduction.html#geocode

Comment: It still doesn't work. Firefox only updates the datalist when the text in the input field is changed and Backspace was pressed. No other key does anything.

Answer (score 0):

All right. No amount of tinkering with zones helped here. I spent almost two days trying to get it working, then I threw it away and replaced the `datalist` with this in ten minutes.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="location" [(ngModel)]="currentLocation">

<div class="panel panel-default panel-body datalist" *ngIf="locationList.length > 0 && !(locationList.length == 1 && locationList[0].description == currentLocation)">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let loc of locationList"><a (click)="changeLocation(loc.description)">{{ loc.description }}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It is a Bootstrap panel which appears every time when there is something to choose from. It works in every browser and there are no update issues. Plus I can detect whether the user has picked an option from the list, therefore I am getting a valid response. It is also easy to add a loader spinner (which I actually did, but I kept this snippet simple).

Lesson learned today: Don't try to use `datalist` in Angular. Just don't.